# Find and Replace entire entries in the entire table using a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

Right now Im using the following script to find and replace text in a MySQL database using phpmyadmin and it works fine.

```
For a single table update

 UPDATE 'table_name'
 SET 'field_name' = replace(same_field_name, 'unwanted_text', 'wanted_text')
```

What I want now is to find entries that contains a specified string, and then replace the whole field.

So for example, If I have the following entries:

```
ABC_1234
ABC_123456789
XYZ_1234
```

And I want to look for the entries that contains "ABC_" and replace the entire field to "FGH-432"

The result of the desired script will give the following output.

```
ABC_1234 > FGH-432
ABC_123456789 > FGH-432
XYZ_1234 (No change)
```

What modification should I make to the script?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: If you're going to use the original column value in the future, it might be best to consider adding another column on the table then update the new value there instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
UPDATE `table_name`
   SET `field_name` = 'FGH-432'
 WHERE `field_name` LIKE 'ABC\_%';
```

Comment: `_` needs to be escaped  `ABC\_%`